# lookup with named range on separate sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm building a spreadsheet that has multiple named ranges on a separate sheet and I want to do a lookup to find the value based on the named range so I don't have to manually enter the cell references.

The current formula I have is:

`=VLOOKUP(D9,INDIRECT("'MACRS Tables'!"&Arkansas!C9),MATCH(K8,INDIRECT("'MACRS Tables'!"&Arkansas!C9),0),0)`

The problem lies in the indirect formula in the match portion of the formula.

It is looking in the entire range instead of looking in just the top row.

How do I fix that?

Comment: What is the value of the cell `Arkansas!C9`? What range does Indirect resolve to?

Comment: The value in Arkansas!C9 is _MA200 which refers to the named range (cells A4:V10 on a separate tab) that the lookup should be using on the other tab.  The indirect portion pulls from the correct named range, it's just the match portion of the formula that isn't working because it is looking at the entire named range (A4:V10) instead of just the top row (A4:V10).  Hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: Well, if the range name _MA200 refers to the range `A4:V10`, why do you expect that referring that range name would NOT return the whole range? How do you expect it to refer to only the first row? You yourself get it wrong in your previous comment when you say `just the top row (A4:V10)` where it should be `A4:V4`. So, if you want to refer to just the first row of that range, you can't use the range name for the whole range. Excel cannot read your mind. The first match should look at the first column of the range, the second match at the first row. You always feed it the whole table.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what I said.  I KNOW that the named range refers to A4:V10.  I want help coming up with a formula that will pull the top row of that particular named range without me having to physically go in and select those rows for the formula, otherwise each time I change which range I need to pull the data from, I would have to go in and manually change that formula each time.  This would defeat the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish entirely if I had to do that.

Comment: I have figured out the problem and got my formula to work. Changed the named range to a table and added "&[#headers]" to the formula.

Comment: Please keep in mind that a huge range of products are discussed on the SuperUser site.  It would be very helpful if you mentioned Excel in the title, and specified your version within the question.  That helps with skimming questions to find those that one can answer. Just remember that the entire world is not bound by Microsoft products, and one shouldn't have to visit your question to know what product(s) you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but the cross-section of a named range and a row can be referred to as

```
index([name],[row number in the range])
```

or as

```
[name] 4:4
```

(where 4 is an absolute reference. Not the 4th in the range)

I think if you replace the [name] with the INDIRECT result, you can just use standard VLOOKUP, without the MATCH.